# How can I click a javascript button on VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am using visual basic 12. There is a web browser in my form. I want to click it but i have a problem. The button is a javascript button. So this code doesn't work:

```
  WebBrowser1.Document.All("button id").InvokeMember("click")
```

Here is the hmtl of button. How can i click it.

```
<p class="text-center panel-text" style="cursor: pointer;" data-bal-yenile="">32.06 KG BAL</p>
```

Comment: That's a paragraph element, not a button.

Comment: Of course you can click it via `InvokeMember("click")`. It doesn't matter what kind of element it is, _"javascript button"_ or not. The problem here is that the element you show us has no ID, therefore `Document.All("<id here>")` won't work.

Comment: That is a paragraph but i can click. @VisualVincent so How can i do it

Comment: I know it is a paragraph, but like I said `Document.All("<id here>")` won't work because your paragraph _**doesn't have an ID**_. Loop through every `<p>` element instead and check `GetAttribute("className")` or `InnerText`.